# A Geometric Distribution Question

Tags: probability, statistics

> Messages relayed over a communication channel have probability p of being received correctly. A message that is not correctly is retransmitted until it is. What value should $p$ have so that the probability of more than one retransmission is less than $0.05$?

I have no idea how to do this problem

Comment: "retransmission" is a bit ambiguous.  Let $X$ be the random variable which counts total number of transmissions required.  Are you asking that $P(X≤2)$ be less than $.05$ or $P(X=1)$ be less than $.05$?

Comment: "retransmission" is explained is his text, so the case $P(X \leq 2) < 0.05$ is the right one

Comment: Either way, this seems like an entirely straight forward problem.  What is $P(X=1)$?  What is $P(X=2)$?   Just add those to get $P(X≤2)$.

Answer (score 0):

For Fist time .5 and for second time .5 and as they are independent.so on second time it will be  (.5*.5)=.25.so from second time it will be lesser than .05.

Comment: what is going on?

Comment: please accept correct ans.